# Is it possible to load huggingface model which does not have config.json file?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to load [this](https://huggingface.co/Carve/u2net-universal) semantic segmentation model from HF using the following code:

```
from transformers import pipeline

model = pipeline("image-segmentation", model="Carve/u2net-universal", device="cpu")
```

But I get the following error:

```
OSError: tamnvcc/isnet-general-use does not appear to have a file named config.json. Checkout 'https://huggingface.co/tamnvcc/isnet-general-use/main' for available files.
```

Is it even possible to load models from HuggingFace without config.json file provided?

I also tried loading the model via:

```
id2label = {0: "background", 1: "target"}
label2id = {"background": 0, "target": 1}
image_processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained("Carve/u2net-universal")
model = AutoModelForSemanticSegmentation("Carve/u2net-universal", id2label=id2label, label2id=label2id)
```

But got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

You will need to **make a lot of assumption** if you don't have the `config.json` and the model card doesn't have any documentation

After some guessing, possibly it's this:

```
from u2net import U2NET

model = U2NET()

model.load_state_dict(torch.load('full_weights.pth', map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
```

---

## In Long

Looking at the files available in the model card, we see these files:

- .gitattributes
- README.md
- full_weights.pth

A good guess would be that the `.pth` file is a PyTorch model binary. Given that, we can try:

```
import shutil
import requests

import torch


# Download the .pth file locally
url = "https://huggingface.co/Carve/u2net-universal/resolve/main/full_weights.pth"
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('full_weights.pth', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)

model = torch.load('full_weights.pth', map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
```

But what you end up with is NOT a usable model, it's just the model parameters/weights (aka checkpoint file), i.e.

```
type(model)
```

[out]:

```
collections.OrderedDict
```

Looking at the layer names, it looks like a `rebnconvin` model that points to the https://github.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net code:

```
model.keys()
```

[out]:

```
odict_keys(['stage1.rebnconvin.conv_s1.weight', 'stage1.rebnconvin.conv_s1.bias', 'stage1.rebnconvin.bn_s1.weight', 'stage1.rebnconvin.bn_s1.bias', 'stage1.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1.rebnconv1.conv_s1.weight', 'stage1.rebnconv1.conv_s1.bias', 'stage1.rebnconv1.bn_s1.weight', 'stage1.rebnconv1.bn_s1.bias', 'stage1.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_var', ...])
```

**ASSUMING THAT YOU CAN TRUST THE CODE** from the github, you can try installing it with:

```
! wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net/master/model/u2net.py
```

And guessing from the layer names and model name, it looks like a U2Net from https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.09007v3

So you can try:

```
from u2net import U2NET

model = U2NET()

model.load_state_dict(torch.load('full_weights.pth', map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Im my experience, when the model attribute under `model=` has erroneous path, it yields the mentioned error:
`OSError [...] does not appear to have the file names config.json`

Make sure the pointer to the model folder (hence `config.json`) is correct.

Actually, the `OSError` itself already communicates there is probably something off path related.